# PrimeNG p-pickList show all buttons enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

in all cases all the icons are enable. I want to enable the icons which make sense and disable the other icons

```html
<p-pickList (click)="refresh();" [source]="available" [target]="selected" 
   sourceHeader="Available" targetHeader="Selected" [responsive]="true">
    <ng-template let-items pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div>{{item.type}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

Comment: seem you are using old version of PrmeNG. you need to update PrimeNG version or handle it in controller.